# Connect to REST API

Tags: java, rest

I have problems connecting with Tradeshift (a Danish company) via their REST API. I have the information needed to connect (token, token secret and taking ID)

This is an HTTP service, I sent the HTTP requests (post, get and put) and I don't get the first response (200 OK) to say that I'm connected.

When I use a clean executable the company where I get the information needed to log me, I sent a request and it displays an error: Invalid token (this is information provided by the company).

I have also tried to connect using a java program I wrote myself. I used Notepad++ to write it. When I compile and I run the program in command line I get errors.
Are imports are made automatically or I have to do something else?

My program is as follows :

```
package com.tradeshift.api.client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;
import com.sun.jersey.oauth.client.OAuthClientFilter;
import com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthParameters;
import com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthSecrets;

public class Sample {

    public static final String HOSTNAME = "https://api-sandbox.tradeshift.com";
    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "OwnAccount"; 
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "OwnAccount";
    public static final String TOKEN = "8Hx7xGR4kmH7Tj2K-Q+39Mrsm6DQ-s";
    public static final String TOKEN_SECRET = "4tUzAVSrBrPXD+a94vEtDW7NcH7XWQXYY7fgcXb@";
    public static final String TENANT_ID = "b59a01fa-8dd7-4d8a-b175-4c72b4a6c891";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client client = Client.create();

        OAuthParameters params = new OAuthParameters().signatureMethod("HMACSHA1").consumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY).token(TOKEN).version();
        OAuthSecrets secrets = new     OAuthSecrets().consumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET).tokenSecret(TOKEN_SECRET);
        OAuthClientFilter filter = new OAuthClientFilter(client.getProviders(),    params, secrets);

        WebResource res = client.resource(HOSTNAME + "/tradeshift/rest/external/network/connections");
        res.addFilter(filter);

        String networkResult = res.header("X-Tradeshift-TenantId", TENANT_ID).header("User    Agent", "TradeshiftJerseyTest/0.1").get(String.class);
        System.out.println(networkResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you get the error 'Invalid Token', the indeed the token is not valid. What is the technical error you are faing?

Comment: I think the executable (rest api explorer) that the company offers, it does not work well.
I write now my code java ( I use the code above) and I'll see if it will work
what do you think?

Comment: You can, but I guess the one provided by the company would be upto-date and would have all the error-handling in place.

Comment: Have you tried to talk with the companies support? I am sure they will help you!

Comment: I don't think they can help me.
I write my code (the one above) using netbeans IDE 7.1.2
I added all the necessary libraries. I have no error code but errors as follows:

Comment: juil. 20, 2012 10:28:57 AM com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider
Grave: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App, could not be instantiated.

Comment: there are also other errors :

Comment: juil. 20, 2012 10:29:00 AM com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider
Grave: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text, could not be instantiated

Comment: this class exists in my library but I don't know how to instantiate the methods
normally you can't edit JAR